# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject'

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, .net-7.0

In my WinForms application I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` as COM like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>6</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>9</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00062fff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And I have create a method to use it like this

```
global using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    public static async Task CreateOutlookEmail(string str, int SubjectId, string[]? attachments = null)
    {
        var application = new Outlook.Application();
        var nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        nameSpace.Logon(nameSpace.CurrentProfileName, string.Empty, false, Missing.Value);
        var oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        oMsg.Display(false); //In order to display it in modal inspector change the argument to true

        var emailDetails = (await GetEmailDetails(SubjectId)).FirstOrDefault();
        oMsg.To = emailDetails?.MailTo;
        oMsg.CC = emailDetails?.MailCc;
        oMsg.Subject = emailDetails?.MailSubject;
        oMsg.HTMLBody = $"{str} {oMsg.HTMLBody}"; //Here comes your body;
        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in attachments)
            {
                oMsg.Attachments.Add(item, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my development machine all works fine but when I trying in other machine, I get this error message

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
> 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application'. This operation failed
> because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
> with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
> following error: Élément introuvable. (0x8002802B
> (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).    at
> SmartWinForm.PL.FrmProjectInfoCH.SendEmail(String str, String strMP)
> in
> C:\Users\MBoua\source\repos\SmartWinForm\SmartWinForm\PL\FrmProjectInfoCH.cs:line
> 317    at SmartWinForm.PL.FrmProjectInfoCH.btnResendEmail_Click(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\MBoua\source\repos\SmartWinForm\SmartWinForm\PL\FrmProjectInfoCH.cs:line
> 254    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_0(Object
> state)    at InvokeStub_SendOrPostCallback.Invoke(Object, Object,
> IntPtr*)    at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj,
> IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

Version of office
Development: Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20000 64-bit
Other Machine: Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20162 64 bits